# Why am I geteting TypeError: 'ActionChains' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas

When I run the code below, I get the error, "TypeError: 'ActionChains' object is not iterable". What am I doing wrong?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Albert/Automation/online-tests/drawingTest.py", line 55, in
>   test_onlineTest
>       self.test_drawGreenPencil()   File "/Users/Albert/Automation/online-tests/drawingTest.py", line 147, in
>   test_drawGreenPencil
>       self.draw_lines(action, [(60, -30), (40, 30), (-40, 30), (-60, -30)])   File "/Users/Albert/Automation/online-tests/drawingTest.py", line 59, in draw_lines
>       for o in offsets: TypeError: 'ActionChains' object is not iterable

Here is the code snippet:

```
def draw_lines(action, offsets, scale=1):
    for o in offsets:
        action.click_and_hold()
        action.move_by_offset(scale * o[0], scale * o[1])
        action.release().perform()




def test_drawGreenPencil(self):
    #click free hand pencil icon
    self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.freeHandPencil).click()
    print("\n" + "Click free hand pencil icon...OK")
    # click line or pen color picker icon
    self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.penColorPicker).click()
    # click the green color from the color pallete sub menu
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        ".line-colors [data-color='brown']").click()
    time.sleep(2)

    print ("Start drawing...")
    # Start mouse interactions
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    action.move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('canvas.upper-canvas')).perform()


    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, 60), (30, 40), (30, -40), (-30, -60)])
    self.draw_lines(action, [(60, -30), (40, 30), (-40, 30), (-60, -30)])
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, -60), (30, -40), (30, 40), (-30, 60)])
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-60, -30), (-40, 30), (40, 30), (60, -30)])

    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, 60), (30, 40), (30, -40), (-30, -60)], 0.8)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(60, -30), (40, 30), (-40, 30), (-60, -30)], 0.8)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, -60), (30, -40), (30, 40), (-30, 60)], 0.8)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-60, -30), (-40, 30), (40, 30), (60, -30)], 0.8)

    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, 60), (30, 40), (30, -40), (-30, -60)], 0.6)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(60, -30), (40, 30), (-40, 30), (-60, -30)], 0.6)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-30, -60), (30, -40), (30, 40), (-30, 60)], 0.6)
    self.draw_lines(action, [(-60, -30), (-40, 30), (40, 30), (60, -30)], 0.6)

    print ("Done.")
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: what's the actual call to these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You have already performed the action. Please re-create it.

```
def draw_lines(self, offsets, scale=1):
    for o in offsets:
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        action.click_and_hold()
        action.move_by_offset(scale * o[0], scale * o[1])
        action.release().perform()

def test_drawGreenPencil(self):
    ...
    self.draw_lines(self, [(-30, 60), (30, 40), (30, -40), (-30, -60)])
```